# Rolling my own __repr__

Tags: python

I want to write my own `__repr__` for some class that I define. I want it to be similar to the default `<__main__.O object at 0x00D229D0>`, except have a few other details in there. How do I reproduce that `<__main__.O object at 0x00D229D0>` thing?

Comment: Are you aware that __repr__ should be a evaluator readable expression? If you want to have user-readable expression you should use __str__

Comment: well either `eval`able or enclosed in angle brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class O(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s.%s object at 0x%x>'%(self.__module__,self.__class__.__name__,id(self))
o=O()
print(repr(o))

# <__main__.O object at 0xb7e7d0cc>
```

Comment: using `__name__` like that will give false results for subclasses not defined in the same module!

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own repr like this:

```
class Test (object):
  def __repr__(self):
    t = type(self)
    return "<Instance of %s.%s at %x>" % (t.__module__, t.__name__, id(self))
```